# C++ Circular Linked List : remove element

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, circular-list

I am done with insertion, search in circular linked list but for removal I am getting compiler errors...

Following is my structure for nodes.

```
 struct node
 {
     int               p_data;
     struct node*   p_next;

     node(node* head, int data)
     {
           p_next = head;
           p_data = data;
     }

     explicit node(int data)
      {
           p_next = nullptr;
           p_data = data;
      }
 };




 node* remove_circular(node* head, node* target)
 {
      if (head == target->p_next)
      {
           delete head;
           return nullptr;
      }

      auto next_pointer = target->p_next;
      target->p_data = next_pointer->p_data;
      target->p_next = next_pointer->p_next;

      delete target->p_next;
      return target;
 }
```

and in main function I call

```
 head = remove_circular(head, head);
 head = remove_circular(head, temp);
```

this is to remove head element and another element that temp points to.
But I am getting errors

Anybody has any idea to remove one element from circular list??

I changed it to delete target->p_next;
but now it deletes everything in the list.
Any idea???

Comment: what is the error message?

Comment: It looks like the line `delete p_next;` in `remove_circular()` might not compile.

Comment: I concur with quamrana. There is no such thing as `p_next` in the scope of `remove_circular()`. And if you think the compiler error is problematic, just wait till you try to *run* this.

Comment: The error is clang llvm 1.0 error exit code 254. I googled it and it is kind of bug that is generated from my "CODE" and I am certain that the error arises from the remove_circular function. Hiding that function, the error goes away.

Comment: It is probably due to what quamrana said. There is no variable called `p_next` within `remove_circular()` scope

Comment: Thanks, so I changed the line to delete target->p_next;   it has not error but it deletes every elements except one elements. What I wanted was to delete only one element in the parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider several things.

1.) the case of an empty list

```
  if(head == nullptr){//Empty list case
      return nullptr;
  }
```

2.) The target to be removed is the head node and this is the only node in the list.

```
  if (head == target && target->p_next == head){
       create a temp node with the data value of target
       target = nullptr;//Since nothing points to target now it is for all intents and purposes deleted from the list but the data is still there so you can do something with it. I assume this is necessary because you return a node *.
       return the temp node
  }
```

3.) Create a loop that iterates through the entire list. You have something that would only delete the next node which works if you have a two item list and target was the second item.

```
  auto next_pointer = head->p_next;//could not be target->p_next as this assumed 
  while (next_pointer->p_next != target){//This while loop traverses the list rather than just deleting the next entry.
```

4.)Inside you loop add a check to see if the list has been traversed and target was never found.

```
   if (next_pointer->p_next == head){
      return nullptr;
   }//end IF
```

5.) Inside the loop add the else case which means target was in an arbitrary location in the list. Since I gave you the rest I'll leave you to get this part. It's not hard just a few lines longer than the statements above.

Comment: I tried to stay as true to your initial algorithm even though a lot of what you are trying does not make sense. I'd recommend using a reference to the node rather than the pointer, and I would return a bool or node rather than a node *.

Comment: I agree with Derek. I believe you should write your algorithm from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

This is how a circular linked list works:

---

[image: linked list example]

---

Each node points to the next in line, and the tail of the list points to the header node. That's the difference from a `circular linked list` to a `regular linked list` (which, in the case above, would make **37** point to a terminator `null`).

In the case of your list having only one object, then it should look something like this:

---

[image: only node situation]

---

So, as you can see, there is no object pointing to `null` anywhere, yet it happens on your code with your `explicit` constructor (which will run if I write `node n = node(12)`).

I suggest you take a look at [this link](http://sourcecodemania.com/circular-linked-lists/) to have a better understanding of how your algorithm should look like.

Answer (score 2):

Once you resolve your compiler error, you are still going to have algorithmic issues. I suggest you draw a circular list on paper and think about the steps required to remove an element. Consider all the cases, for example: empty list, list of 1 item, element not in the list, etc.