# need help doubly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I am creating a doubly linked list in c++. code looks fine but when i tried to add second node in the list the program crashes. there is something wrong with insert() function but don't know how to resolve it.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Node{
    int info;
    Node* next, *back;
    friend class LinkedList;
};

class LinkedList{
private:
    Node* head;
public:
    LinkedList();
    void print();
    void find(int, Node**, bool *);
    void insert(int);
    void remove(int);
    void destroylist();
    void modify(int, int);
    bool checkifempty();

};

LinkedList::LinkedList(){
    head=NULL;
}

void LinkedList::print(){
    Node* tmp;
    tmp=head;
    while(tmp!=NULL){
        cout<<tmp->info<<endl;
        tmp=tmp->next;
    }
}


void LinkedList::find(int key, Node** loc, bool *found){
    *loc = head;
    bool more=true;
    while((*loc)!=NULL && (*loc)->info)){

        *loc=(*loc)->next;


    }
    if (*loc==NULL)
    {
        *found=false;
    }
    else if ((*loc)->info==key){

        *found = true;
    }

}



void LinkedList::insert(int key){

    Node *NewNode,*loc=NULL;
    bool found;

    find(key,&loc,&found);
    //Creating NewNode
    NewNode=new Node;
    NewNode->info=key;
    //if list is empty
    if (checkifempty())
    {
        NewNode->next=NULL;
        head=NewNode;
    }
    //otherwise
    else
    {
        NewNode->back=loc->back;
        NewNode->next=loc;
        loc->back->next=NewNode;
        loc->back=NewNode;
    }
    //Connecting pointers to complete insertion


}

void LinkedList::remove(int key){
    Node* loc; bool found;
    find(key,&loc,&found);
    loc->back->next=loc->next;
    loc->next->back=loc->back;
    delete loc;
}

void LinkedList::destroylist(){
    Node* tmp;
    while(head!=NULL){
        tmp=head;
        head=head->next;
        delete tmp;
    }
}

bool LinkedList::checkifempty(){
    return (head==NULL?true:false);
}


int main(){
    LinkedList mylist;
    mylist.insert(10);
    mylist.insert(15);
    mylist.insert(11);
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Look at the answers here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18364601/c-circular-linked-list-remove-element/18366104#18366104 Hopefully it puts you on the right track. I also recommend using the find() from the algorithm library instead of the find you have written.

Comment: "I am creating a doubly linked list in c++."   *Why?*

Comment: Why are you using a separate find function to get the last node? You are already using head to keep track of the first node. Similarly, use another node tail to keep track of the last node. It is optimal. Performance wise, your find() will take a serious hit when the number of added nodes increases.

Comment: Use std::list. don't reinvent the wheel

Comment: If you listen to too many commenters here, you might get the idea that learning anything is pointless, because somebody else already knows how to do stuff and you can use a readymade solution. Don't listen. Keep studying.

Comment: @molbdnilo +1 for such a nice guidance.Good Work.Keep the begginers motivated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your insert function, check the pointer you retrieve from `find`:

```
if (loc != NULL) {
  // insert pointer into non-empty list
```

The `find` function and the pointer you retrieve from it is really where the problem lies, because you do not check whether it has returned a valid pointer.

Comment: Also, the `remove` function does not check whether an item to be removed has been found in the list...